# How to expand an string to a charractere in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the file named: italo.jpeg

How to extract italo (before period) using:

```
set file=italo.jpeg
set prefix=%file:~[arguments]%
```

I've tried %file:~0,"."% but didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=." %%b in ("%file%") do set "prefix=%%b"
```

or, since this is a filename,

```
for %%b in ("%file%") do set "prefix=%%~nb"
```

Documentation : enter `for /?` at the prompt.